# Laravel IO Socket and redis over SSL https connection

Tags: laravel, ssl, io, redis

Currently have IO sockets with laravel broadcasting with redis working perfectly. Until I then set up an SSL cert on the domain.

I have redis-server running on port 3001.

Then there is a socket.js set to listen to 3000.

My JS on the page I listen via io('//{{ $listen }}:3000').

Any guidance would be great on how to get this working over https. Would I just use 443 as the port?

Thanks.

My socket.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('notifications', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, setup your `serverOptions` object:

```
var serverOptions = {
    port: 3000,
    host: 127.0.0.1, //address to your site
    key: '/etc/nginx/ssl/your_site/server.key', //Or whatever the path to your SSL is
    cert: '/etc/nginx/ssl/your_site/server.crt',
    NPNProtocols: ['http/2.0', 'spdy', 'http/1.1', 'http/1.0']
}
```

For the `NPNProtocols`, you may not care for all of them, but they're provided for reference.

Now just create the server:

```
var app = require('https').createServer(serverOptions),
    io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

This should be pretty plug and play into your source at his point.\

As a side note your stuff is completely wide open and anyone can listen on your web socket, so nothing should be sent that is private through here. If you need to make your data private, then you're going to need 1 of two things;

1. Something like `JWT-Auth Token`
2. Something custom that interface with the `Redis` queue:

Here's an example of the latter:

```
var SECRET_KEY = '<YOUR_LARAVEL_SECRET_KEY>';
var laravel_session_parser = {
    ord: function (string) {
        return string.charCodeAt(0);
    },
    decryptSession: function (cookie, secret) {
        if (cookie) {
            var session_cookie = JSON.parse(new Buffer(cookie, 'base64'));
            var iv = new Buffer(session_cookie.iv, 'base64');
            var value = new Buffer(session_cookie.value, 'base64');
            var rijCbc = new mcrypt.MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'cbc');
            rijCbc.open(secret, iv);
            var decrypted = rijCbc.decrypt(value).toString();
            var len = decrypted.length - 1;
            var pad = laravel_session_parser.ord(decrypted.charAt(len));
            return phpunserialize.unserialize(decrypted.substr(0, decrypted.length - pad));
        }
        return null;
    },
    getUidFromObj: function (obj, pattern) {
        var regexp = /login_web_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/gi;
        if (pattern) {
            regexp = pattern;
        }
        var u_id = null;
        for (var key in obj) {
            var matches_array = key.match(regexp);
            if (matches_array && matches_array.length > 0) {
                u_id = obj[matches_array[0]];
                return u_id;
            }
        }
        return u_id;
    },
    getRedisSession: function (s_id, cb) {
        var _sessionId = 'laravel:' + s_id;
        client.get(_sessionId, function (err, session) {
            if (err) {
                cb && cb(err);
                return;
            }
            cb && cb(null, session);
        });
    },
    getSessionId: function (session, _callback) {
        var u_id = null,
            err = null;
        try {
            var laravelSession = phpunserialize.unserialize(phpunserialize.unserialize(session));
            u_id = laravel_session_parser.getUidFromObj(laravelSession);
        } catch (err) {
            _callback(err, null);
        }
        _callback(err, u_id);
    },
    ready: function (socket, _callback) {
        if (typeof socket.handshake.headers.cookie === 'string') {
            var cookies = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
            var laravel_session = cookies.laravel_session;
            var session_id = laravel_session_parser.decryptSession(laravel_session, SECRET_KEY);

            laravel_session_parser.getRedisSession(session_id, function (err, session) {
                if (!err && session) {
                    laravel_session_parser.getSessionId(session, function (err, user_id) {
                        if (user_id) {
                            _callback(null, session_id, user_id, laravel_session)
                        } else {
                            _callback(new Error('Authentication error'), null);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    _callback(new Error('Authentication error'), null);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can just have `IO` get an instance of the individuals `session` when they establish a connection to socket.io

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    laravel_session_parser.ready(socket, function(err, session_id, user_id, laravel_session) {
        //log out the variables above to see what they provide
    });
});
```

Note, I prefer to use `dotenv` in `NodeJS` to share environment variables between Laravel and Node.

Then you can do `process.env.APP_KEY` and you don't need to worry about sharing variables.

Also of note, that script above is not complete and is not production ready, it's just meant to be used as an example.

Comment: I kind of see what your saying. I will include what I have in the main question as not too sure how to implement what you suggest.

Comment: @Dean Just do `app.listen(serverOptions.port)` and not `http.listen(3000...`

Comment: Thanks, defo pointing me in the right direction. Connection is untrusted though?

Comment: Make sure you don't have assets loaded through `http://` on an `https://` page. :)

Comment: Don't think that is issue I am afraid. When I visit https://IP-ADDRESS:3000 I see a message saying connection is not secure :(

Comment: @DeanCollins Do you have an `SSL Certificate` ?

Comment: Yeah! moment of stupidty. Was trying to reference and IP instead of the domain name. Thanks for you help!!